# Modify fillin command in exam class

Tags: exam

When using the exam class, is there a way to change the formatting of \fillin[][] command so I can increase the vertical space between text and underline?
please see the output of the following code

```
\documentclass[answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsbsy,amssymb,amsthm,xcolor}
\usepackage{blkarray,mathrsfs,amsrefs,amsfonts,enumerate,pifont,enumitem}
\newcommand{\ans}{\vskip0.01in {\color{blue}\textbf{Answer:}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question 
$f(x) = x-1$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x+1},$ find:
\begin{enumerate}[font=\color{magenta} \Large, label=(\alph*)]

    \item $(g\circ g)(x)$ and $(g\circ g)(5)$
            \ans \fillin[$(g\circ g)(x)=g(g(x))=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1}+1}=\frac{1+x}{2+x}$ and $(g\circ g)(5)=\frac67$][4.5in]
\end{enumerate} 
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

Thanks